# Three.js: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new to Three.js and not completely familiar.
In my new project, I'm trying to load a gltf file with `GLTFLoader()`. But it gives me an error that I don't understand it.
This is the first time I had this error.

This is the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Application.js:41
    at GLTFLoader.js:147
    at GLTFLoader.js:1639
```

But when I import it to https://gltf.insimo.com, it shows very well. So this mistake of mine.
This is how I loaded my gltf:

```
this.gltfLoader.load('/corolla.gltf', (_corolla) => {
            this.resources.corolla = _corolla.children[0]

            // Set environment
            this.setEnvironment()
        }, (xhr) => {
            console.log(Math.round(xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
        }, (error) => {
            console.log('An error happened: ', error);
        });
```

Comment: What's at that line (1639)?

Comment: What's inside the `_corolla`? and inside `children`? Put the code in the question. Probably, `children` is undefined.

Comment: If the error is occurring here: `this.resources.corolla = _corolla.children[0]`, it is saying `children` is undefined. Put a breakpoint on that line and inspect `_corolla` to see what's wrong there.

Comment: `this.setEnvironment()` could do *anything*. There's no way of telling what the problem is when you don't show us the minimum necessary relevant code.

Comment: @TheJim01 yes it was `children[0]`. After removing, it solved.